# Make local requirements.txt file available to microk8s stable/airflow

Tags: kubernetes

According to [the stable/airflow docs](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/airflow#installing-dependencies) you can:

> mount a file to /requirements.txt to get additional Python modules for your DAGs to be installed on container start. Use the extraConfigMapMounts configuration option for this.

But the README is a bit thin on documentation for this option:

```
| airflow.extraConfigmapMounts  | Additional configMap volume mounts on the airflow pods. | [] |
```

Can anyone give an example of how I can link a requirements.txt file stored locally to my (local) kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 0):

The `values.yaml` file in the root of the `stable/airflow` repo has an example of how to do this:

```
airflow:
  extraConfigmapMounts: []
  # - name: extra-metadata
  #   mountPath: /opt/metadata
  #   configMap: airflow-metadata
  #   readOnly: true
  #
  # Example of configmap mount with subPath
  # - name: extra-metadata
  #   mountPath: /opt/metadata/file.yaml
  #   configMap: airflow-metadata
  #   readOnly: true
  #   subPath: file.yaml
```